# Parental Controls Always Allow does not work for Avid Media Composer

Tags: macos, imac, parental-controls

I've enabled Parental Controls on a new Nov 2012 iMac being used in a school for public access (OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion) and have restricted the applications this account can use. Everything works fine with the exception of *Avid Media Composer* (the main reason we purchased the iMacs...). Avid Media Composer is marked as an application that the account is allowed to use in the parental control settings.

When I try to start Avid Media Composer under this account, a message pops up saying that this user doesn't have permission to use the application, giving the following three options:

- Always Allow...
- Allow Once...
- OK

When clicking **Allow Once**, I have to enter the admin account username and password and the app starts without problems. But when I click **Always Allow**, it asks for the admin account as well, but then pops up the same message again and again. I have verified that I'm using the right admin account username and password, but it's still refusing to run the application.

When I disable parental controls, everything works, but the moment I turn it on again, it fails, despite having Avid Media Composer in the list of allowed applications for this account.

In the Console application, I can see the following error message whenever this happens:

> com.apple.launchd.peruser.504: ([0x0-0x1de1de].com.avid.mediacomposer[2033]) 
>   Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13

Has anybody else experienced this or knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem too!
Turn off parental control and it works fine.
Interesting as I have two Mac Pros and one with PCs on does allow MC to work.
The other with the PCs on and it does not.
I suppose best answer is to turn off Parental Controls for an separate account just for users whom use AVID.